# Continuity of $f(x)=[x]+ \sqrt{x-[x]}$

Tags: functions, continuity

Consider the function $f(x)=[x]+ \sqrt{x-[x]}, \, x\in \Bbb R$ ; where "$[ \space ]$" denotes the greatest integer function. It is obvious that if $b$ is an integer, then

$$\lim_{x\to b-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b-}[x] + \sqrt { \lim_{x\to b-}x - \lim_{x\to b-}[x] } =b-1+\sqrt {b-(b-1)}=b-1+1=b$$

$$\lim_{x\to b+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b+}[x] + \sqrt { \lim_{x\to b+}x - \lim_{x\to b+}[x] } =b+\sqrt {b-b}=b,$$ and

$$f(b)=[b]+ \sqrt{b-[b]}=b+\sqrt {b-b}=b,$$ hence $f(x)$ is continuous for all integer values of $x$.  Is $f(x)$ continuous for all non-integer values of $x$ also, i.e. is it true that $f(x)$ is continuous for all $ x \in \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: yes,it is continuous because graph is straight line.

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi: No, [it is not](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28x%29%2Bsqrt%28x-floor%28x%29%29).

Comment: @CameronBuie: But its graph tells another story at integers. What the problem?

Comment: @Babak: What do you mean? It is continuous, but *not* a straight line, though it certainly corresponds to the identity function at integer values.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I mean this second point you say about integers value. Thanks

Comment: @CameronBuie Graph is not exactly straight line but look like a straight line from the graph we can say that it is continuous for all x in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi: What do u do whit that radical in the function? Straight line? I can't see such that and Maple agrees with me.

Comment: It is not differentiable at the integers.

Comment: @CommonerG Editing [ ] denoting the greatest integer function into the ceiling function is wrong since $[x]\leqslant x$ but $\lceil x\rceil\geqslant x$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write $f(x)$ as

$$ f(x) = x + g(x) \quad \text{where} \quad g(x) = \sqrt{x - [x]} - (x - [x]). $$

It is clear that $g(x) = \sqrt{x} - x$ on $[0, 1)$ and $g(x+1) = g(x)$.

From this observation it is easy to prove that $g$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ (the point $x = 1$ only matters), and then this continuity extends to $\Bbb{R}$ by periodicity of $g$. Therefore $g$ is continuous and hence the same is true for $f$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then for some $\epsilon >0$, $B(x,\epsilon) \cap \mathbb{Z} = \emptyset$. Then $\lfloor y \rfloor $ is constant for $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$. Let $k = \lfloor y \rfloor $. Note that if $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$, we have $y > k$.

For $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$, we have $f(y) = k + \sqrt{y-k}$, which is continuous (in fact smooth, since $y > k$).

$f$ is not differentiable at the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Since continuity is a local property, for any $x_0$ not an integer, $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $g(x)=[x_0]+\sqrt{x-[x_0]}$ is continuous at $x_0$.  This is because $g(x)=f(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$.  Since $g(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$, so is $f(x).$